# Wrong raster format when multiplying rasters using rioxarray

Tags: python, python-xarray, rasterio

I'm trying to add two rasters created using the rioxarray package. Both have the same xy resolution/grid (3905y, 13566x), but when added together suddenly the grid structure changes (1629y, 6799x). How to add two rioxarray rasters while keeping the same grid? I think it may have something to do with NaN values, but not sure.

[image]

Comment: [please don't post images of code or data](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) - they aren't searchable or readable by screen readers. Instead, please copy the terminal output into the question as a code block. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

this looks like a case of slightly mismatched coordinates. you can test whether your coordinates are exactly identical with [`xr.align(POP_roi, wasteDay, join='exact')`](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.align.html).

Assuming they're not lined up, you can address this by rounding the coordinates, e.g. with

```py
POP_roi['x'] = np.round(POP_roi['x'], 6)
POP_roi['y'] = np.round(POP_roi['y'], 6)
wasteDay['x'] = np.round(wasteDay['x'], 6)
wasteDay['y'] = np.round(wasteDay['y'], 6)
```